# get input text through ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

How would I change this script,it is set for file upload i can get all to go into database from file other than the input text,I want it to get the input text too and then I can insert the input text into database through php.

Can anyone help??

```
<script>

function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0]; //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData(); formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait while file is saved!";
}

function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}

function errorHandler(event){ 
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event){ 
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}

 </script>


<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="Eid" name="name1" />
    File:<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress><br />
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()"><br />
    <h3 id="status"></h3> <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: `formdata.append("name1", _('Eid').value);`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
formdata.append("name1", $('#Eid').val());
```

I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to append the input text value to the formdata parameter which is used for the ajax-request. Try adding the following:

```
formdata.append("name1", _("Eid").value);
```

after

```
var formdata = new FormData(); formdata.append("file1", file);
```

I have not testes this code, but by `_("Eid")` you would get the input text element and by `.value` its value. The in your php-script (file_upload_parser.php) you should be able to read the input fields value from the formdata parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using an append function to add the file to your formdata. So all you need to probably do is use the same function to append your input. Something like:

```
var formdata = new FormData(); 
formdata.append("file1", file);
// Add input field value
formdata.append("name1", _('Eid').value);
```